# Android heap management for Bitmaps - how does Android not run out of memory?

Tags: android

I have a `GridView` with JPEGs loaded from the network.

I'm trying to find out the memory limits of my app.

I wrote a Robotium test to rapidly scroll through the `GridView` from top to bottom.
Even when I have almost 300 JPEGs, the heap measured through `Runtime.freeMemory()` and the native heap through `Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize()` are stable.

I am testing on the Eclair emulator, since my app needs to support Eclair.

Where does Android get the memory to store the Bitmaps? The numbers don't seem to add up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the Adapter you use for the GridView re-use views? If so its garbage collecting the images from the re-used imageviews once there no longer a reference to them.

Comment: Yes, that looks like it. The GridView recycles them with the RecycleBin and ScrapViews.